# Getting a Bootstrap.css list-group to take up the entire width of a mobile app page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app with Twitter Bootstrap and PhoneGap.  What I am looking for is a simple list-group where each item takes up the entire width of the page.  Currently, the list-group has left and right padding that I want to get rid of.  Screen shot is below:[image]

My html for the page is as follows:

```
<html doctype and head above>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Books Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Add</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="after-header">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Title: Catch-22</strong><p>Author: Joseph Heller</p></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Title: A Farewell to Arms</strong><p>Author: Ernest Hemmingway</p></li>
              </ul>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The after-header class is defined as follows:
    .after-header {
      padding:50px;
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
.after-header { padding:50px 0px; }
```

looks promising to me.

See this live: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/tzxhp/

Comment: Bootstrap automatically adds in some padding due to the native grid structure, so you may actually need to have a negative left/right padding. I think 15px is the default Bootstrap offset, so you may need to do `padding:50px -15px;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Xenocideae . In this case I'm not seeing that you need any negative left and right padding because list items aren't inside the usual Bootstrap container > row scaffolding. Check the result of my suggestion @ http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/tzxhp/embedded/result/ and let me know if I'm missing something